# The [groovy] tag became ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Ask Ubuntu has a [groovy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/groovy) tag that is dedicated to “a dynamic language for the Java Virtual Machine”.

However, [Groovy (Gorilla) is the name of Ubuntu 20.10](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19374/ubuntu-groovy-gorilla-20-10-is-now-released-and-posts-about-it-are-generally) and users started to (mis)use the tag for Ubuntu 20.10 – there are 3 such questions currently but I’d expect more to come.

Should the original tag be renamed (to `jvm-groovy`, for example)? Should the [groovy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/groovy) description be improved, so users are aware of its intended meaning?

Comment: [Created synonym](https://askubuntu.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all). Two posts remain with the tag but they will be deleted within a week by roomba. I will check back at the weekend to make they are gone and edit them if not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Great catch! Another alternative - we could remove the tag altogether. Do we actually need a tag for that language? There are only 20 questions in the tag (including the wrongly tagged ones) and most of them are about [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation). If they were about features of the language itself, or about platform-independent issues with using in it, they would be off-topic anyway.

Version tags are available (although some folks feel they should not be used at all) in the form [16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/16.04) [18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/18.04) [20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/20.04) [20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/20.10) etc. Usually we have synonymised them so that, for example, [xenial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xenial) maps to [16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/16.04) (attempts to use the former add the latter). We could do the same with [groovy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/groovy) if we remove it from the java-related questions.

Comment: The opinion of the community seems to be pretty clear. What are the following steps? Should we remove [[tag:groovy]] from the Java-related questions manually?

Comment: Yes @Melebius I guess we better get a move on and do it :) sorry for the delay

Answer (score 3):

Great catch! Renaming the tag to [jvm-groovy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/jvm-groovy) as you suggested is a good idea. Editing the usage guidance should also be done if the tag is renamed, but just fixing the usage guidance alone is very unlikely to prevent the tag from being misused.

Version tags are available (although some folks feel they should not be used at all) in the form [16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/16.04) [18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/18.04) [20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/20.04) [20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/20.10) etc. Usually we have synonymised them so that, for example, [xenial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xenial) maps to [16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/16.04) (attempts to use the former add the latter). We could do the same with [groovy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/groovy) if we rename the current [groovy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/groovy).